# Error: Await must not be called on the UI thread

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an EditText which facilitates the autocompletion of Google Maps places.
Its throwing this error:

```
await must not be called on the UI thread.
```

On changing the text in the EditText, the AutoCompletePlace API is called.
How can I solve the issue?

```
@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            try {
                GeoDataApi geoDataApi = Places.GeoDataApi;
                PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> autocompletePredictions = geoDataApi.
                        getAutocompletePredictions(GoogleClient.getIstance(), searchLoc.getText().toString(), null, null);
                AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictionBuffer= autocompletePredictions.await();
                System.out.println("Size: " + autocompletePredictionBuffer.getCount());
                for(int i=0; i<autocompletePredictionBuffer.getCount(); i++){
                    Place p= (Place) geoDataApi.
                            getPlaceById(GoogleClient.getIstance(), autocompletePredictionBuffer.get(i).getPlaceId());
                    searchList.add(
                            new SearchListProvider(
                                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                                    autocompletePredictionBuffer.get(i).getFullText(null).toString(),
                                    p)
                    );

                }


            }
            catch (Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Message: "+e.getMessage());
                Log.d("Message: ", e.getMessage());
            }
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), searchLoc.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should use AsyncTask here. Because await is stopping the current thread. So you should send your request to API in Worker thread. Then you can update result in onPostExecute()

Comment: AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictionBuffer= autocompletePredictions.await(); ----- I should do this inside Async Task.

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala That will be ok If you just put all related logic into doInBackground.

Comment: I had a similar issue where I was calling `OptionalPendingResult<T>.await()` within my activity's `onCreate()` method. Moving it to an `AsyncTask` solved the issue.

For context, I have an activity that performs a set of checks to determine what state the user and app are in, and forwards them to the correct activity. Part of that was a Google sign-in silent auth check using `GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn()` which requires you to use `await()`.